# Value from FORM is not passed to Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have written a html form and trying to retrieve the values in node js server.

```
<form action="/newPost" method="post">
First Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>

Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
    const hbs = require('hbs');
    var {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
    var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
    var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
    var {User} = require('./models/user');
    var app = express();
    hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.post('/newPost', (req, res) =>{
 console.log(req.body.text);
 console.log(req.params.firstname);
 console.log(req.body.firstname);
 res.send(req.body.firstname);
    });
```

expecting mickey but shows undefined

Comment: Do you get any message in the browser when the form is submitted?

Comment: `console.log(req.body.firstname)` should've worked

Comment: just add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`   it will work for sure :)